# Ajax Table refresh - Site content should stay above the Table

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html-table

I want to have some content above the table, but every time the table is updated the content above my table is shown below the table. I don't get it because this content is not in between the refresh ... How could I fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> <font size="2"> 
        <table class="table table-condensed" border="1" id="usertable"></table>
        </font>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">Option 1</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">Option 2</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="checkbox">Option 3</label>
        </div>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <div class="alert alert-success"> <a href="#" class="alert-link">Die Übersicht zu Drive-Now München lädt... Bitte einen Moment Geduld!</a>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //..//
                $('#usertable').append(

                function() {
                    return "<tr class=" + farbe + ">" +
                    //..//
                    "<tr>";
                });
            })
            }).always(callJSON);
            }, 2000);
            }
            $(callJSON);
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script to use `.before()` instead of `.append()`:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //..//
            $('#usertable').before(

            function() {
                return "<tr class=" + farbe + ">" +
                //..//
                "<tr>";
            });
        })
        }).always(callJSON);
        }, 2000);
        }
        $(callJSON);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The content is still below the table... :(

Comment: @user2718017 I just realized that your table is inside the `<head>` of your HTML. It's not good practice to put content in there. Move the table to the `<body>` and try again. You should also move your `<script>`s to the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the html renders a "tbody" with your table, and if so your content is placed outside of this tag. Try...

```
$('#usertable').find('tbody').append(...);
```

Just an idea